Using OpenCV CMake targets from within a project's source tree
I'm attempting to use OpenCV 4.10.0 in a CMake project on Windows. I understand that the usual way to do this would be to use find_package(OpenCV), but in my case I need to be able to build and use the OpenCV project completely from source, so can't simply use a binary distribution installed at the system level.
My current approach is to clone the OpenCV repository as a Git submodule, and then use add_subdirectory() to add it into my overall CMake project build.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(my-opencv-project)

# Set some options and configure OpenCV
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(BUILD_PERF_TESTS OFF)
set(BUILD_TESTS OFF)
add_subdirectory(opencv)

# Then create an executable that depends on OpenCV
add_executable(testproject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testproject PRIVATE opencv_core)

The test project is super simple, just to try and prove that the build works:
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

OpenCV builds fine, but my test project does not. I get the error: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory.
I know that opencv_core is the name of the core module target in the OpenCV build tree, and I know from listing the properties on the target that it does add the correct directory for this header include to be found. I would therefore expect that the include path would be used automatically when I specify opencv_core as a dependency of my executable, but that doesn't seem to be happening. OpenCV does seem to have a whole host of funky custom macros for hooking its modules up together, so there could well be something going on in all of that that's tripping me up.
Is actually possible to use OpenCV targets in this way, or will I be forced to do a two-step compilation where I build and install OpenCV locally, and then compile my test project making reference to that installation? I'd rather avoid this if I possibly can.

It seems that OpenCV project doesn't ship its targets with INTERFACE (or PUBLIC) include directories. So, when use these targets, you need to specify include directories manually. Like in that answer.

@Tsyvarev Thanks, I guess that's the least worst option given the circumstances, I'll give it a try.

you're missing "find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )". See the doc

"in my case I need to be able to build and use the OpenCV project completely from source, so can't simply use a binary distribution installed at the system level." you still should use find_package() in that case. just make sure cmake finds your build of opencv. look into the source of FindOpenCV.cmake to figure out how it finds the opencv build. then, cmake only needs to find that FindOpenCV.cmake file.

My 2 cents,
TLDR: OpenCV 4.X do not support supper build nor provide ALIAS nor use cmake namespace so the only way to consume it is through cmake build, install, find_package() way...
Dev Note:

OpenCv use ocv_add_library target macro to wrapp add_library()
ref: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.10.0/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake#L1575-L1618

Which use _ocv_append_target_includes() to fill PRIVATE target_include_directories() only...
ref: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.10.0/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake#L1538-L1558


If you really need to "FetchContent/add_subdirectory()" (e.g. cross-compile, sandboxed build (python wheel pkg as a swig wrapper)) then you may try to hack this macros to add the relevant bits... aka
target_include_directories(${t} PUBLIC 
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>

Related OpenCV Issue:

It's not possible to use OpenCV headers unless they are installed into a system include path. #5989
Suggestion: use opencv:: namespace for cmake imported targets #13117
Modernize CMake to CMake3 #25005


Thanks, I think I may have to go down the find_package() route after all. The important bit for my use case is that everything I use is built from source, so a two-step build to allow for find_package() would work I suppose, even if it's not ideal.
