How to fix build error when CPMAddPackage opencv?
It aways error when I use CPM.cmake CPMAddPackage add opencv to my project.
CPMAddPackage(
    NAME OpenCV
    GITHUB_REPOSITORY opencv/opencv
    GIT_TAG 4.10.0
    OPTIONS
        "ENABLE_CCACHE ON"
        "BUILD_opencv_dnn ON"
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF"
        "BUILD_opencv_apps OFF"
        "BUILD_opencv_python2 OFF"
        "BUILD_opencv_python3 OFF"
        "BUILD_JAVA OFF"
)

cmake is ok, but build error:
ninja: error: '_deps/opencv-build/modules/core/opencl_kernels_core.hpp', needed by '_deps/opencv-build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_autogen_timestamp_deps', missing and no known rule to make it

I tried build opencv directly with same options, it is build success.

Note, that OpenCV project is not ready to be used via add_subdirectory or FetchContent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79042700/using-opencv-cmake-targets-from-within-a-projects-source-tree. And CPMAddPackage is effectively FetchContent.
